# Writing to the Task.Stop field Microsoft Project

Tags: vba, ms-office, ms-project

I am attempting to take status off of a task by setting the task.stop field to an earlier date using vba.  I am getting a "Runtime Error 1101: The argument is not valid."

I have tried the following two lines of code:

```
Task.Stop = CurrentProj.StatusDate
```

and

```
Task.SetField FieldID:=pjTaskStop, Value:=CurrentProj.StatusDate
```

Current values are:

```
CurrentProj.StatusDate = 10/31/2013 17:00:00  
Task.Stop = 11/5/2013 17:00:00
```

both are of Variant/Date DataType

I could not find and use of the Stop field in any forums.  Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: I have now found out that the schedule my macro was trying to manipulate has the drop down greyed out on the stop field. I'm looking to see if there is a setting which changes the stop field from read/write to read only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "Split in Progress Tasks" option must be selected or the Stop field will be read only. File>Options>Schedule>Scheduling options for this project>Split in progress tasks. Checking that box solved the problem.